# Javascript .indexOf says 2 equal elements are not equal

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.makeArray($('ul#NavAContent li')).indexOf($('ul#NavAContent li#A1'))
```

The li element with id A1 is in the ul#NavAContent, but the indexOf function returns **-1**, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with `$('ul#NavAContent li#A1').index()`?

Comment: @BradChristie or just `$('#A1').index()` ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not comparing elements but jQuery objects (which are containers for elements);

```
$("#footer") !== $("#footer")
```

but

```
$("#footer")[0] === $("#footer")[0]
```

(Tests were ran on this page)

So do this:

```
$('#NavAContent li').toArray().indexOf( $('#A1')[0] );
```

I removed some qualifiers hoping to god that you are not using multiple elements with same id.

Comment: Thanks! this is working. There are no elements with the same id's. This code works nice

Answer (score 1):

The `jQuery` function returns an array-like object containing all of the elements matched by the given selector. This is a new array each time, so the array you're searching for with `indexOf` is a different array than the one given to `makeArray`.

This works (and should demonstrate the problem):

```
$.makeArray($('ul#NavAContent li')[0]).indexOf($('ul#NavAContent li')[0])
```

Comment: More concisely, `var l = $.makeArray($('ul#NavAContent li')); console.log(l); console.log(l.indexOf($('li#A1')[0]));` (You can continue to makeArray from the original list, you just have to make sure you're only checking if a single element is then in the collection (not a list of matches, or in this case a list with only one element).) OP is basically asking for `[li,li,li,li].indexOf([li])` instead of `[li,li,li,li].indexOf(li)` (which is why the `[0]` is necessary)

Comment: I'm searching for the $('ul#NavAContent li#A1') element in the $.makeArray($('ul#NavAContent li')) array, so when i put [0] behind it, it searches #A1 only in the first li, it has to search in the entire ul